Relation between Coulomb's constant and Permittivity of free space
In Colomb's Law,
$F=\frac{k q1 q2}{r^2} $
The constant $k$ is written as
$k=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$,
where $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space.
Q) Why is it written so?
I have heard people say that it is because of Gauss's Law, but I feel that is circular argument because
$\phi = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$ itself arrives due to the fact that
$k$ is written in terms of permittivity.
Context: Electrostatics

It is largely conventional.  The factor of $4\pi$ is inserted because lots of integrals over angles have $4\pi$ factors in them (v.g. $\int \sin\theta\,d\theta d\phi=4\pi$)
It also depends on the definition of the charge and, ultimately, on the unit system.  In Gaussian units, Coulomb's law reads
$$
\vec F=\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\hat r
$$
so factors like $4\pi \epsilon_0$ are actually absorbed into the definition of the charge in this unit system.

SI units are intended to be practical. Defining $\epsilon_0$ the way it is done in SI units has the advantage that the factors of $4\pi$ appear in formulae involving spherical fields, while they don't appear in formulae involving rectilinear fields. So, for example, the idealized parallel plate vacuum capacitor has capacitance $C=\epsilon_0 A/d$, ($A$ is plate area, $d$ is plate spacing). Simple, practical.
Theorists who work with spherical problems every day often prefer Gaussian units, where $k=1$, and most of the tedious $4\pi$ factors disappear, simplifying the formulae they use.
